# configure LAMP, cannot copy my files to /var/www/html/

Tags: linux, lamp, chmod

i don't know how to **chmod** files

after typing `# ls -al /var/www/html` i get this :

1. drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Feb 25 23:23 .
2. drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4096 Feb 25 21:27 ..
3. -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   34 Feb 25 23:26 index.php

---

this time being my second time trying to install LAMP on Fedora 15 with the first time ended up reinstall the whole system because i **mis-chmod** some files

new to linux so please bear with me and be specific

and also first time post my question up here

thx in advance

Comment: This is more an OS question than a programming question.  You might have more luck on http://superuser.com (though you may want to be more specific about what the actual problem is; what i'm seeing isn't that big a deal, absent some error message or actual problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod` is a command used to change the permissions of files in UNIX. While typing `ls -al /var/www/html` you get a list of files (and hidden files because of the `a` option) and the permissions they have.

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Feb 25 23:23 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4096 Feb 25 21:27 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 34 Feb 25 23:26 index.php
```

It can be seen as: `ooogggrrr` meaning `o` owner of the file, `g` group of the owner and `r` rest of users. Each field can be r/- (value 4), w/- (value 2) and x/- (value 1), meaning read, write and execute.

Then, if you want a file to *ch*ange the *mod*es, you have to do **chmod XXX file**, where each X corresponds to one group.

So if you want a file to be written, read and executed by the owner, you need 4+2+1=7 permission. We normally set 755 permissions to files in webservers, so that all users can  access to all contents, but just the owner can write in there.

So, to sum up, if you have to chmod files on your fedora, you have to give more permissions to the files in a certain directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to a terminal and write:

```
sudo nautilus /
```

then, a window will be open and you will have all the permissions to change whatever you want - be careful!

Then, you can go to /var/www/ and change the permissions of the folder "html" and its files, by a right click on the folder/files, with a user friendly environment...